# Не получается применить функцию для русского языка

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь применить вот эту функцию на список текстов, но на выходе ничего не меняется. Скорее всего функция не работает, так как написана для английского языка, но я не знаю как можно её изменить, чтобы она работала и для русского.

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("russian")
def tokenize(tweet):
    """Removes punctuation & excess whitespace, sets to lowercase/n
    and stems tweets. Returns a list of stemmed tokens."""
    tweet = " ".join(re.split("[^a-zA-Z]*", tweet.lower())).strip()
    tokens = [stemmer.stem(t) for t in tweet.split()]
    return tokens`
```

Comment: Посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696028/snowballstemmer-for-russian-words-list

Comment: Подозреваю, что в регулярное выражение надо добавить русские буковки.

Comment: По идее тут вообще русские буквы должны исчезнуть после такой обработки, посмотрите на шаблон регулярки, по которому тут `re.split` делается.